# Hibernate : Using AND combined with OR in a single query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC project where I am required to search for some information with given parameters. Here is my current HQL query, which most likely wont get me data I require.  :

```
 org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("From GroupNotes as " +
                "n where n.ownednotes.msectionid=:msectionid and n.noteDisabled=false and n.noteInActive=false order by n.mnoteorder");
        query.setParameter("msectionid", msectionid);

    Query hiddenNotesQuery = session.createQuery("from GroupNotes as gn where gn.ownednotes.msectionid=:msectionid and gn.privateNoteUser=:username");
        hiddenNotesQuery.setParameter("msectionid", msectionid);
        hiddenNotesQuery.setParameter("username",person.getUsername());

        List<GroupNotes> groupNotesList = new ArrayList<>();

        groupNotesList.addAll(query.list());
        groupNotesList.addAll(hiddenNotesQuery.list());
```

I would like something like this :

```
from GroupNotes as n where (n.ownednotes.msectionid=:msectionid and n.noteDisabled=false and n.noteInActive=false and n.privateNoteUser=:"") or (n.ownednotes.msectionid=:msectionid and n.privateNoteUser=:username n.noteDisabled=false and n.noteInActive=false)
```

I hope the query I am looking for makes sense, so basically it should retrieve GroupNotes which are not disabled and not active, but also it should it should pay attention that it is only retrieving Private GroupNotes for the specific user and thus in the first bracker there is privateNoteUser as "". I don't know what I should have there.

If any doubts, kindly let me know. How can I form this query.

Update :

```
@Override
    public List<GroupNotes> listGroupNotesBySectionId(int msectionid) {
        Person person = this.personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("From GroupNotes as " +
                "n where n.ownednotes.msectionid=:msectionid and ((n.noteDisabled=false and n.noteInActive=false and n.privateNoteUser=:blank) or (n.privateNoteUser=:username and n.noteDisabled=false and n.noteInActive=false)) order by n.mnoteorder");
        query.setParameter("msectionid", msectionid);
        query.setParameter("msectionid", msectionid);
        query.setParameter("username",person.getUsername());
        query.setParameter("blank",null);
        List<GroupNotes> groupNoteses = query.list();

}
```

I created the query like this, but I am getting back no data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from GroupNotes as n where n.ownednotes.msectionid=:msectionid  
and (
 ( n.noteDisabled=false and n.noteInActive=false and n.privateNoteUser=:"") 
   or
 ( n.privateNoteUser=:username n.noteDisabled=false and n.noteInActive=false)
)
```

Comment: Can you please check the edit on the post, I did the query as you said, I am getting back null data.

Comment: i think the query  and syntax is right.Are you getting any Hibernate errors? Since you have access to the columns and tables - can you validate that the query is doing the right conditional clauses? i.e. we are checking for the right fields / values in the where clause statements.

Comment: Yes, if I break it down and call like the way I was usually calling, then it works. There is data in tables as I can see in PGAdmin. I get no hibernate errors.

Comment: can u paste the query u use in pgadmin. Just wanna compare.

Comment: This is a HQL query, not a SQL query...How can I get output in PGAdmin for an HQL query. I will need to translate it...Give me sometime..But i ran a for loop on query.list and used System.out, it didnt go inside the loop itself as the list was empty.

Comment: Just checked, null, Here is the query : select * from groupnotes where msectionid=5150 and((notedisabled=false and noteinactive=false and privatenoteuser like '') or (privatenoteuser='myemail@gmail.com' and noteinactive=false and notedisabled=false));

Comment: Any ideas because i tried using like operator in HQL query too, still nothing.

Comment: in the pgadmin SQL query..what is the parameter here - privatenoteuser like ''? Did u put in a value for this parameter also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81872/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-paul-john).